# two-way data binding not being established on particular property

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to establish a two-way data binding in order to edit schema properties on the front end.  My title edit and choices edit work perfectly, but I can't seem to get content in scene.content to bind.

Here's the edit form I'm using:

```
<form name="sceneForm{{scene._id}}" data-ng-submit="update(scene)" data-ng-if="scene.editing">

  <h5>Title</h5>
  <input type="text" id="sceneForm{{scene._id}}" required data-ng-model="scene.title"></input>
  <br>

  <h5>Edit Content</h5>
  <li data-ng-repeat="content in scene.content">
    <input type="text" id="sceneForm{{scene._id}}" data-ng-model="content"></input>
   </li>
  <br>

  <h5>Edit Choices</h5>
  <li data-ng-repeat="choice in scene.choices">
    <input type="text" id="sceneForm{{scene._id}}" data-ng-model="choice.sceneId"></input>
    <input type="text" id="sceneForm{{scene._id}}" data-ng-model="choice.displayText"></input>
  </li>

  <!-- OK/CANCEL -->
  <button type="submit">OK</button>
  <button ng-click="reset(scene)">Cancel</button>
</form>
```

And here's my schema:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var sceneSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
  content: [String],
  choices: [{
    sceneId: String,
    displayText: String
  }]
});

module.exports = exports = mongoose.model("Scene", sceneSchema);
```

I'm very new to AngularJS, so any thoughts on why this may be happening are appreciated!

Comment: What's in the `scene.content` ?

Comment: `scene.content` contains an array of strings.  It's basically meant to edit sections of a text based game.  Content contains each line.

Comment: there will be scope issue if you bind a array of string instance as ng-model

Comment: You cannot use ng-model inside ng-repeat'

Comment: Thanks for the responses.  binariedMe, why is it working for my choices array?